# Поменять значение true и false

Tags: javascript

Как можно поменять? `true` на верно, а `false` на неверно

```js
  function allowDrop(ev) {
      ev.preventDefault();
    }

    function drag(ev) {
      ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
    }

    function drop(ev) {
      ev.preventDefault();
      var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
      ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
    }
      function check() {
      const parent = document.querySelector('#div2')
      const child = document.querySelector('#drag2')
      const result = parent.contains(child)

      document.getElementById('win').innerHTML = result;
    }
```

```css
  #div1,
    #div2 {
      min-width: 200px;
      height: 50px;
      margin: 10px;
      padding: 10px;
      border: 1px solid black;
    }

    img.imgelem1 {
      width: 50px;
    }

    img.imgelem2 {
      width: 100px;
    }

    td {
      text-align: center;
    }
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
      <td class="imgtd">
        <div class="imgcontainer">
          <img src="https://png.icons8.com/color/50/000000/1.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="drag1">
          <img src="https://png.icons8.com/color/50/000000/2.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="drag1">
          <img src="https://png.icons8.com/color/50/000000/3.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="drag2">
          <img src="https://png.icons8.com/color/50/000000/4.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="drag2">
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>        
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div id="div2" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <button class="buttonresult" onclick="check();">CHECK</button>
  <p id="win"></p>
```

Дополнил вопрос

Comment: Вам дали правильный ответ, но сам вопрос ошибочный. Зачем что-то менять в нативных функциях? Создайте свою собственную функцию log и возвращайте через неё что угодно в любом формате.

Comment: Да, ошибся, вопрос доплонил

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так вы хотели?

```js
function allowDrop(ev) {
      ev.preventDefault();
    }

    function drag(ev) {
      ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
    }

    function drop(ev) {
      ev.preventDefault();
      var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
      ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
    }
      function check() {
      const parent = document.querySelector('#div2')
      const child = document.querySelector('#drag2')
      const result = parent.contains(child)

      document.getElementById('win').innerHTML = result?'верно':'неверно';
    }
```

```css
#div1,
    #div2 {
      min-width: 200px;
      height: 50px;
      margin: 10px;
      padding: 10px;
      border: 1px solid black;
    }

    img.imgelem1 {
      width: 50px;
    }

    img.imgelem2 {
      width: 100px;
    }

    td {
      text-align: center;
    }
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
      <td class="imgtd">
        <div class="imgcontainer">
          <img src="https://png.icons8.com/color/50/000000/1.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="drag1">
          <img src="https://png.icons8.com/color/50/000000/2.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="drag1">
          <img src="https://png.icons8.com/color/50/000000/3.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="drag2">
          <img src="https://png.icons8.com/color/50/000000/4.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="drag2">
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>        
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div id="div2" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <button class="buttonresult" onclick="check();">CHECK</button>
  <p id="win"></p>
```

Answer (score 2):

Путём подмены нативной функции на свою собственную, я полагаю.

```js
let was=console.log
console.log=(...args)=>{
 args=args.map(v=>{
   if(typeof v!='boolean') return v
    return v?'верно':'неверно'
  })
 was(...args)
}
console.log('Вот так:',true,false)
```

Comment: Вопрос дополнил, посмотрите пожалуйста